# ESP32 FreeRTOS pin interrupt ISR handler core 0 panic (C++)

Tags: arduino, esp32, freertos, arduino-c++, platformio

Currently I am trying to attach a pin interrupt whose ISR is to call `xTaskResumeFromISR` or `xQueueSendFromISR`. The ISR gets called correctly, but the code to execute results in a *core 0 panic*.

Here are the implementation details.

**PlatformIO**: platform = espressif32 @ 6.0.1, framework = arduino, board = esp32dev

**Header file (Worker.h)**

```
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>

class Worker {
  public:
    Worker(uint8_t pinExtInterrupt);
    bool startTask(void);
  protected:
    // static wrapper for task creation
    static void  staticRun(void *arg) {
      reinterpret_cast<Worker *>(arg)->run();
    }

    // actual task's logic
    void run(void);

    // static interrupt handler
    static void staticIsrHandler(void* arg);

    // actual interrupt handler
    void isrHandler();
    
    TaskHandle_t _taskHandle = nullptr;
    uint8_t _pinExtInterrupt;
};
```

**Source file (Worker.cpp)**

```
#include "Worker.h"

Worker::Worker(uint8_t pinExtInterrupt) {
  _pinExtInterrupt = pinExtInterrupt;
  pinMode(pinExtInterrupt, INPUT);
}

bool Worker::startTask(void) {
  BaseType_t xReturned = xTaskCreate(staticRun, "Worker", 2048, this, 5, &_taskHandle);
  gpio_set_intr_type(static_cast<gpio_num_t>(_pinExtInterrupt), GPIO_INTR_NEGEDGE);
  gpio_install_isr_service(0);
  gpio_isr_handler_add(static_cast<gpio_num_t>(_pinExtInterrupt), staticIsrHandler, NULL);
  return true;
}

void Worker::run(void) {
  for (;;) {
    vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    // LOGIC
  }
}

void IRAM_ATTR Worker::staticIsrHandler(void* arg) {
  reinterpret_cast<Worker*>(arg)->isrHandler();
}

void IRAM_ATTR Worker::isrHandler() {
  xTaskResumeFromISR(_taskHandle); // ###### THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION ######
}
```

**Error**
*Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

0x400d1d00:0x3ffbeaac in Worker::isrHandler() at ...*

But what works is if you replace `xTaskResumeFromISR` e.g. with `digitalWrite(..)`.

Need to fix the problem above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call here:

```
gpio_isr_handler_add(static_cast<gpio_num_t>(_pinExtInterrupt), staticIsrHandler, NULL);
```

assigns a null pointer for the ISR handler's context data. As a result, when your static ISR is called:

```
void IRAM_ATTR Worker::staticIsrHandler(void* arg) {
  reinterpret_cast<Worker*>(arg)->isrHandler();
}
```

arg is a null pointer, causing the access to `_taskHandle` to fail here:

```
void IRAM_ATTR Worker::isrHandler() {
  xTaskResumeFromISR(_taskHandle); 
}
```

If you replace your `gpio_isr_handler_add` call with the following:

```
gpio_isr_handler_add(static_cast<gpio_num_t>(_pinExtInterrupt), staticIsrHandler, this);
```

everything should work.

Comment: Hero! You saved my weekend. Somehow I've overseen the null pointer argument completely!